# Java jButton needs to be clicked twice before starting activity

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, netbeans-7

I'm building a GUI in Netbeans 7.1 that represents an infusion pumps for a project on hospital equipment. Pressing jButton1 should show a certain jLabel with indicates that an infusion is running. Pressing jButton1 again should stop it. The only problem I have is that the button needs to be clicked twice before it works the first time. After that, it works exactly how I want it to work. I have searched multiple threads on this issue, but other solutions don't seem to work. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

```
  package infusion;
  public class Infusion {
    static Interface screen;

    public Infusion(){

        screen = new Interface();
        screen.setVisible(true);
        screen.jLabel3.setVisible(true);
        screen.jButton1.setVisible(true);
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Infusion infusion = new Infusion();
    }
   }
```

This is the code for the user interface (mostly generated by Netbeans). The implementation of jButton1ActionPerformed is the only bit of code that I have adapted.

```
package infusion;

    public class Interface extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        boolean pump1Running = false;
        /**
         * Creates new form Interface
         */
        public Interface() {
            initComponents();
        }


        /**
         * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
         * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
         * regenerated by the Form Editor.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
        private void initComponents() {

            jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
            jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
            setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 562));
            setResizable(false);

            jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 540));

            javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
            jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
            jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGap(0, 800, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );
            jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGap(0, 540, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );

            jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Pauze.png"))); // NOI18N
            jLabel3.setText("Infusion Paused");

            jButton1.setText("Start infusion");
            jButton1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(36, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 189, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 649, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap())
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 22, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(51, 51, 51)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 64, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 59, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>

            //Booleans



        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            if (pump1Running == false){
                jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Pauze.png")));
                jLabel3.setText("Infusion Paused");
                jButton1.setText("Start Infusion");
                pump1Running = true;
            }
            else {//if (pump1Running == true){
                jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/arrows64.gif")));
                jLabel3.setText("Running infusion");
                jButton1.setText("Stop Infusion");
                pump1Running = false;
            }     
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                        

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /*
             * Set the Nimbus look and feel
             */
            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
            /*
             * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
             * default look and feel. For details see
             * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
             */
            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Interface.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Interface.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Interface.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Interface.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //</editor-fold>
            /*
             * Create and display the form
             */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    new Interface().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
        // Variables declaration - do not modify
        public static javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        public javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
        public javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
        private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
        // End of variables declaration

    }
```

Comment: sounds like a focus related problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem: pump1Running = false, so when you click the button, it sets the label and image to the same thing it is to start with. Then it switches it to true, then it can switch to the other label/image.

```
        if (pump1Running){
            jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Pauze.png")));
            jLabel3.setText("Infusion Paused");
            jButton1.setText("Start Infusion");
            pump1Running = !pump1Running;
        }
        else {//if (pump1Running == true){
            jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Pauze.png")));
            jLabel3.setText("Running infusion");
            jButton1.setText("Stop Infusion");
            pump1Running = !pump1Running;
        }
```

This switches pump1Running back and forth and fixes the problem.

Comment: I can't believe that the solution was so simple that I overlooked this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: (If this is the answer, remember to accept it as the answer).